# Unable to update MongoDB from edit profile page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I am trying to update my particular user database on edit profile page.But I don't know where I am going wrong in it.

```
 {{!--editProfile.hbs--}}
      <link   rel="stylesheet"  href="myprofile.css">
    <title>Edit Profile Page</title>

<body>
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
          <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

          <input type="file" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- edit form column -->
      <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
        <h3>Personal info:</h3>

         <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/addDB" method="POST"> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="username">Username:</label>

            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input class="form-control " type="text" id="username" name="username"placeholder="Username">
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input class="form-control " type="password" placeholder="Password"name="password">
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <input class="form-control " type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone"name="phone">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
             button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
             </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

//index.js

```
var express=require('express');

var app=express();

var session=require('express-session');

var mongoClient=require("mongodb").MongoClient;

var db;

mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017",function(err,client){
if (err) throw err;
db=client.db("myDBS");
});

app.use(
    session({secret: "Express session secret"}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false}));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");});

//For Inserting new User in DB
app.get('/addS',function(req,res){
    res.render('addNewUsers');
});

app.post("/add",function(req,res){
    db.collection("users").insert(req.body);
    console.log("Insert successfully");
    res.render("myprofile");
});

//for updating DB

app.post('/addDB', function(req, res, next) {
                var data = {
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                phone:req.body.phone
              };
             // var id = req.body.id;
      mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err, db) {

     db.collection('users').updateOne({$set: data}, function(err, result) {
                     console.log('User updated');
                  db.close();
                });
              });
            });

   app.get("/edit",function(req,res){
    res.render("editProfile");
});

app.get("/dmyprofile",function(req,res){
    res.render(307,"/myprofile");
});

app.post("/myprofile",function(req,res){
    db.collection("users").find().toArray(function(err,result){
        if (err) throw err;
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if(req.body.email==result[i].email &&
                 req.body.password==result[i].password)
                 {
            req.session.loggedIn=true;
                 }
        }
        res.redirect("/user");
    });
     });
app.get("/user",function(req,res){
    if(req.session.loggedIn==true){
        res.render("myprofile");
    }else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});

app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect("/");
});
app.listen(3355,function(){
    console.log("Listening on 3355");
});
```

when I am clicking on save changes it is showing me db.collection not a function. Though my insert route is working fine but update part is not working.

All other routes are working fine. But this update part is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way you are connecting to MongoDB.

To have direct access to the collections after connecting to Mongo you must have the database name in the connection string, like in the code below:

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDBS", function(err, db) {
     db.collection('users').updateOne({$set: data});
});
```

The other way to get access to the collections is connecting to Mongo and choosing the which database to use right after, like you did upper in your code:

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017",function(err,client){
    if (err) throw err;

    db=client.db("myDBS");

    db.collection('users').updateOne({$set: data});
});
```